# Calling googleapis_auth flow from AngularDart component

Tags: dart, google-oauth, angular-dart

I'm trying to trigger OAuth flow using the `googleapis_auth` package from an AngularDart component (`MaterialButtonComponent`).

The examples from `googleapis_examples` ([here](https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis_examples/blob/master/drive_search_web/web/index.dart#L29)) show how to do this with a raw `ButtonElement` to avoid the pop-up being blocked by the browser. However, when I follow the same pattern using the AngularDart style using `(trigger)="method()"` or `(click)="method()"`syntax my pop-up gets blocked.

Current code:

drive_component.html:

```
<material-button icon (trigger)="save()"
             class="icon-button">
<material-icon icon="archive"></material-icon>
```

drive_component.dart

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';
import 'package:blue_rose_character_creator/src/character/character.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_browser.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart';

final identifier = new ClientId(
    "<my-client>.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    null);
const scopes = const [DriveApi.DriveScope];

@Component(
  selector: 'drive',
  templateUrl: 'drive_component.html',
  styleUrls: const ['drive_component.css'],
  directives: const [CORE_DIRECTIVES, materialDirectives],
  providers: const [materialProviders],
)
class DriveComponent {
  @Input() Character character;

  void save() {
    createImplicitBrowserFlow(identifier, scopes)
        .then((BrowserOAuth2Flow flow) {
      // Try getting credentials without user consent.
      // This will succeed if the user already gave consent for this application.
      return flow.clientViaUserConsent(immediate: true).catchError((_) {

        //I've removed the loginButton from the flow, since AngularDart
        //doesn't pass this around.
        //loginButton.text = 'Authorize';
        //return loginButton.onClick.first.then((_) {
        return flow.clientViaUserConsent(immediate: false);
      }, test: (error) => error is UserConsentException);
    });
  }
```

What would be the correct AngularDart style to get the pop-up unblocked? Is there one?

Comment: Did you try `(click)="method()"`? I'm aware that this might cause other issues, but it would be interesting if this would do something.

Comment: Same effect, unfortunately. I'll update the question. Good idea though, thanks!

Comment: Does it work with a normal `<button (click)="method()">log in</button>`?

Comment: Nope, still blocks the popup.

Comment: What code do you actually call on `(click)="..."` or `(trigger)="..."`?

Comment: The save method up there in `dart_component.dart`.

Comment: I don't really understand what you try to accomplish, but I think the problem is that the code that opens the popup needs to be directly called from the click handler, not some async code or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is you have an async operation between the `save` call an the `clientViaUserConsent` call.

I'd try calling `createImplicitBrowserFlow` when the component loads – and don't enable save until you have a `flow` object stored.

Make sense?

Comment: Thank you, this cracked it! Would it be alright if I edited the answer to show what I changed to make it work to save some time for the next person?

Comment: I think so...just add it in a new section at the bottom...or something. :-)